# Google Sign-In (website) - javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-signin

I'm facing a problem for quite a while and I can't find a solution for it.

I want to integrate Google Sign-in to my website and I don't get a respond through the JavaScript that's input in the webpage when I sign in. 
I followed [this article](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference)
and yet I cannot solve this issue.

```
<head>

    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
    <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="THIS_IS_MY_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com">

</head>


<body>

    <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>

    <script>
        function onSignIn(googleUser) {
            console.log("Signed in!");
        }
    </script>

</body>
```

the function (onSignIn) that's presented, does not run when I sign in using Google. Can anyone help?

**EDIT:**

It seems that on an online host this script works well so I guess I'll keep it this way since the website is going to be hosted anyways.

Answer (score 0):

a fiddle of your code (with a valid client id) works - [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k1dbl4ck/y4asfcqv/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=y4asfcqv) - but reports redirect_uri_mismatch when you click on it.

so you need to go to :

https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/consent

and configure your projects oAuth settings.

If you are developing on localhost, edit your hosts file and add the line

```
    127.0.0.1 localhost.com
```

to it, and then set the "Homepage URL" on Google Developers Console to

```
    localhost.com
```

as well.

Thus when you load localhost.com in your browser, it resolves to your host, and the .com keeps the oAuth valid hostname requirement happy.

Comment: still doesn't work... I also didn't have a redirect_uri_mismatch error displayed